# How can I send a GraphQL request from Unreal Engine C++?

Tags: c++, graphql, unreal-engine4

I successfully made a regular HTTP request and got the response back. Now I am trying to do the same with GraphQL. The GraphQL request is returning 200 in Postman with the expected JSON body, but when I try to do the same in C++, I get a 400 Bad Request. My code is below, with access tokens removed.

```
AApiClient::AApiClient()
 {
     //When the object is constructed, Get the HTTP module
     Http = &FHttpModule::Get();
 }
 
 void AApiClient::BeginPlay()
 {
     Super::BeginPlay();
     MyHttpCall();
 }
 
 void AApiClient::MyHttpCall()
 {
     TSharedRef<IHttpRequest, ESPMode::ThreadSafe> Request = Http->CreateRequest();
     Request->OnProcessRequestComplete().BindUObject(this, &AApiClient::OnResponseReceived);
     
     Request->SetURL("https://{my-access-token}@{my-url}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/graphql.json");
     Request->SetVerb("POST");
     Request->SetContentAsString("{\"query\": \"{ node(id: \"gid://shopify/Product/{my-product-id}\") { id ... on Product { title } } }\"}");
     Request->SetHeader(TEXT("User-Agent"), "X-UnrealEngine-Agent");
     Request->SetHeader("Content-Type", TEXT("application/json"));
 
     Request->ProcessRequest();
     UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Request sent."));
 }
 
 void AApiClient::OnResponseReceived(FHttpRequestPtr Request, FHttpResponsePtr Response, bool bWasSuccessful)
 {
     UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("Response received"));
     UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("The response code is {%i}"), Response->GetResponseCode());
     FString ResponseString = Response->GetContentAsString();
     UE_LOG(LogTemp, Warning, TEXT("The response is {%s}"), *ResponseString);
 }
```

One thing I should note is that it only worked in Postman after I turned on the setting labeled "Disable cookie jar". I may need to do something analogous to that in C++ but haven't discovered how that's done. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Is `{my-access-token}` perhaps in a `aaa:bbb` format? If so, that's HTTP Basic Auth. Maybe the C++ library doesn't properly extract it and put it in a header? Another idea: take Telerik Fiddler and inspect the actual requests going out both from Postman and UE. You should find the difference easily.

Comment: Have you checked whether the UEngine HTTP library actually supports the `http://...@...` syntax? Try setting the `Authorization` header or [`X-Shopify-Access-Token` header](https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/getting-started#authentication).

Comment: @Vilx- Yes it is in that format. I'm working on moving the access token to a header.

Comment: @Botje I think you're right. That's part of the problem. If a POST request uses HTTP auth on the Shopify API, you get a 200 error code every time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it to work. One of the problems I was running into is explained here:

> Shopify doesn't support cookies in POST requests that use basic HTTP
> authentication. Any POST requests that use basic authentication and
> include cookies will fail with a 200 error code.

From here: https://shopify.dev/tutorials/authenticate-a-private-app-with-shopify-admin#generate-credentials-from-the-shopify-admin

These are the changes I made:

1. Remove the access token from the URL.

`Request->SetURL("https://{my-shop-url}.myshopify.com/admin/api/2021-04/graphql.json");`

2. Directly set the GraphQL query as the content without removing whitespace (rather than including the query as a JSON element as in my question above).

`Request->SetContentAsString("{  node(id: \"gid://shopify/Product/{my-product-id}\") {    id    ... on Product {      title    }  }}");`

3. Change the Content Type header to use GraphQL.

`Request->SetHeader("Content-Type", TEXT("application/graphql"));`

4. Add the **app password** as the access token header.

`Request->SetHeader("X-Shopify-Access-Token", TEXT("{my-app-password}"));`

With these changes made, I'm getting a 200 OK response with the content I'm looking for.